# spring-data-neo4j 2.2.0 has java.security.AccessControlException in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-data-neo4j

GAE is throwing the following error with spring-data-neo4j 2.2.0.  Is there a way to disable threads in spring-data-neo4j?

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
```

(spring-data-neo4j 2.1.0 apparently didn't play with threads and does work in GAE.)

Comment: Are you trying to run Neo4j on GAE? I thought that was not possible ...

Comment: I'm not running neo4j in embedded mode. I should be able to submit rest requests to a server, right?